# Seeking Automated Sensor Tracking Solution in ROS 1- Handling Large Data and Performance Issues

Tags: ros, sensor

I could use some advice on how to track sensor data while the robot is in motion. Let me explain further: I'm working with ROS 1, and I know I could use the 'rosbag' commands to save a topic where the sensor status would be stored. The issue with this method is that it generates really large files for my sensor. Another problem is that I need an automated way—something that doesn't rely on a user command in the bash terminal. I've tried integrating my Python script that controls the robot's movements on the ground, but everything slows down significantly in the simulation.

Thanks in advance!